# Try to pass the initial data in the form with the field ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

My problem is that I can not save the form. I think the problem lies in the `event` field in the `Register` model.
I do not want the user to choose an Event from the list, I want it to happen automatically, hence the code: `form.cleaned_data['event'] = kwargs['pk']`
This part of code `kwargs['pk']` is from url.

Please any hint if this is good approch to dealing with forms and hint to solve my problem. Below is my code.

Thanks :)

Models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()
    text = models.TextField()
    image = FilerImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    flag = models.ForeignKey(Flag)
    free_places = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def slug(self):
        return slugify(self.title)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('events:detail', args=[self.slug, self.id])


class Register(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_event_name(self):
        return self.event
```

View:

```
class EventDetailView(DetailView, ModelFormMixin):
    model = models.Event
    form_class = forms.RegisterForm

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('events:list')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.get_form()
        print(kwargs['pk'])
        print(self.form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(form.cleaned_data['event'])
            form.cleaned_data['event'] = kwargs['pk']
            form.save()
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

My form:

```
class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Register
        fields = ('event', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'company', 'street', 'post_code', 'city', 'email', 'phone_number',)
```

My template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <ul>
        <h1>Detail page:</h1>
        <li>{{ object.title }}</li>
        <li>{{ object.text }}</li>
        <li>{{ object.date }}</li>
    </ul>

    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is to insert into a validated data. Instead of that,

Initialize the form with request POST data which should include "event" key and its value you got from kwargs['pk']. Then validate it and save. You will not get validation errors, as well as the value will be saved.

Basically, even the event id you get from the url that has to be validated. Django does with db level check against the pk value you passed when you call is_valid.